How to compute the rank of a matrix with variable entries
Say I have like a 6x6 matrix with some variables inside. How would I solve for when the matrix has a rank of say 4? MatrixRank assumes that the variables inside are independent. This exact question was asked here before but with no real answer given.
Here is an example 6x6 matrix for your convenience:
{{a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16}, 
 {a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26}, 
 {a31, a32, a33, a34, a35, a36}, 
 {a41, a42, a43, a44, a45, a46}, 
 {a51, a52, a53, a54, a55, a56}, 
 {a61, a62, a63, a64, a65, a66}}


Show your 6x6 matrix, please.

@A.Kato the point is that it should apply to any 6x6 matrix, but I have edited the question to provide the matrix

Ok. Then answer is well-known. The necessary and sufficient condition is precisely given by the condition that determinants of all (r-1) x (r-1) minors vanish and that of some r x r minor does not. So if rank 4 case, you first list up all possible 3x3 sub-matrices (there are 20 x 20 = 400 such matrices), and check that they all have determinant zero, and then check that some of 15 x 15 = 225 of 4x4 minors have nonzero determinant.

Note: a_11 is not a proper variable. It is 11 times the Pattern a_. Your matrix above is equivalent to the scalar product of the pattern a_ and the matrix consisting of the integer indices (a_ * Table[10 i + j, {i, 6}, {j, 6}]). If you're calling MatrixRank on that, you will get 2, which will probably seem wrong to you.

My previous comment was wrong: All determinants of (r+1) x (r+1) minors vanish, while there is a r x r minor whose determinant is non-zero.

This is not a very well constructed question, given the absence of a concrete example. I'll use the 3x3 matrix from the linked post.
mat = {{x, x*z, w - 2*x}, {w*z^3, x*y, z}, {y^2 - z^3, x + w, z + x^5}};

The condition that it have rank 1, say, is that the constant and linear terms of the characteristic polynomial vanish (so zero is an eigenvalue of multiplicity 2). These coefficients are polynomials in the parameters and can be found as below.
clist = CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, t], t];
clist[[1 ;; 2]]

(* Out[122]= {x^7 y + (-w - x) x z + x^2 y z - w^2 (-w - x) z^3 + 
  2 w (-w - x) x z^3 - w x^6 z^4 - w x z^5 - w x y (y^2 - z^3) + 
  2 x^2 y (y^2 - z^3) + x z^2 (y^2 - z^3), -x^6 - x^2 y - x^6 y - 
  x z + (w + x) z - x y z + w x z^4 + w (y^2 - z^3) - 2 x (y^2 - z^3)} *)


The whole point of the question is to be general. Can the method you have used be extended to a generic 6x6 matrix where each entry is a variable? What are the conditions on the 36 variables such that the matrix has rank 4?

Such questions are often considered outside the scope of the forum. As for using a different matrix, the code will be the same.

@jujumumu Doesn't this answer work with any (square) matrix mat and any rank?
